# Dynamically resizing fixed menu on site

Tags: html, css

The goal here is to get the secondary fixed flavors menu to dynamically resize with the main content.

The site can size up to 1086px and size down to 960px width.

The secondary menu needs to resize the same. I've tried multiple ways of doing this and have not explored JS solution just yet. I'm not sure where I'd even start at this point.

Here is the site:

https://devtest.eboost.com/

I currently have the menu set to 960px width and is centered.

Thanks,

George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the widths of the links to width: 20%; That should split the 5 up into 20% or whatever you have the wrapper set to.

```
        a {
          display: block;
          float: left;
          width: 20%;
        }
```

Look into border-box as well to deal with the padding problems I anticipate you will run into next.

Comment: Thank you sir! I was going crazy with messing with the thing. Thanks for pushing me in the correct direction for solution :-) Now finally can move onto other portions of the project.